# Formatting UITextField or UiTextView

Tags: iphone

using iphone sdk 3.0 can someone say how to format a UITextField or UITextView
so that when the user enters a phone number it will be formatted the way
the contacts application formats the number ie +1 (888) 465-375
How to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For a UITextView you can use:

```
[aTextView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeAll];
```

I don't think there is such an option for a UITextField.